# Converting integer to character in java display un readerble wrong values

Tags: java

I use simple method to change string values without changing original length of string.then back convert change the text back into pure string(into Original text).

My code :

```
    String someText = "abcdefgHIJKLMN";
    char[] data = someText.toCharArray();
    int LEN = someText.length();
    char[] datas = new char[LEN];

    System.out.println("Original Text ("+String.valueOf(LEN)+"): "+someText);
    for (int i = 0; i < LEN; i++) {
        data[i] = Character.valueOf((char) i);
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(i) + " = " + String.valueOf((char) i));
    }

    System.out.println("Add 10 into each charactor : "); // ex a =1 , a+10 : now it's 'k'
    for (int i = 0; i < LEN; i++) {
        char c = Character.valueOf((char) (Character.getNumericValue(Character.valueOf(data[i])) + 10));
        datas[i] = c;
        System.out.print(String.valueOf(c));
    }

    System.out.println("Subtract 10 from each charactor : ");// ex k =11 , k-10 : now it should be 'a'
    for (int i = 0; i < LEN; i++) {
        char c = (char) (Character.getNumericValue(Character.valueOf(datas[i])) - 10);
        System.out.print(String.valueOf(c));
    }
```

But after adding and subtracting that loops dose not display anything.
If there is any solution to achieve this type of things without changing original length of text?

This is the thing I want to do:

Let say character value of `a` is `97` then we add 10 into it:`(97+10) = 107` now it's not `a` it's should be different letter such as `k` because 107 character value is :`K`

Comment: Why are you setting `data` to `someText.toCharArray()` and then overwriting it with U+0000, U+0001, U+0002 etc? It's not really clear what you're trying to do, but it's very broken...

Comment: What result would you expect for "`Z+10`"?

Comment: Oh it prints stuff, just not what you're expecting it to print - your problem is that you're expecting `1` to translate into `a` when it doesn't. Try `char a = 'a'; System.out.println((int) a);` and you'll see what int value 'a' *actually* has. `1` is actually "START OF HEADING", which you can see by doing `Character.getName(1)`.

Comment: I want to get this.
`let say a = 14 then we add 5 into 14 (14+5) then it's not a it should be change. it's simple encryption`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in line 8:

```
data[i] = Character.valueOf((char) i);
```

When i = 0, data[i] is not 'a'. 'a' has a value of 97 (hex 61):
http://www.utf8-chartable.de/

Moreover you can add chars using '+' but the result of '+' operator is integer, so you only have to cast it to char - ie.

```
char c = (char) (data[i] + 10);.
```

Also in your loops you used print instead of println, that's why the output was not so clear. Try the code below and see if it works out for you.

```
String someText = "abcdefgHIJKLMN";
    char[] data = someText.toCharArray();
    int LEN = someText.length();
    char[] datas = new char[LEN];

    System.out.println("Original Text ("+String.valueOf(LEN)+"): "+someText);
    for (int i = 0; i < LEN; i++) {
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(i) + " = " + data[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("Add 10 into each charactor : "); // ex a =1 , a+10 : now it's 'k'
    for (int i = 0; i < LEN; i++) {
        char c = (char) (data[i] + 10);
        datas[i] = c;
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(c));
    }

    System.out.println("Subtract 10 from each charactor : ");// ex k =11 , k-10 : now it should be 'a'
    for (int i = 0; i < LEN; i++) {
        char c = (char) (datas[i] - 10);
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(c));
    }
```